# On clicking a custom tab in Magento admin,Invalid config field backend model

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I have module a module as Mak_Gift there I am creating a custom tab.(Mak is namespace and Gift is module name.)

When I click the tab created in the Magento admin, I am getting following error

```
Invalid config field backend model: gift/system_config_backend_date
```

I have created the system.xml file  with following code

```
....

<backend_model>gift/system_config_backend_date</backend_model>

....
```

I have the Date.php file at following location

app\code\local\Mak\Gift\Model\System\Config\Backend\Date.php

```
class Mak_Gift_Model_System_Config_Backend_Date extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
     protected function _beforeSave()
    {
    }
}
```

*config.xml*

```
<global>
    <models>
        <mak_gift>
            <class>Mak_Gift_Model</class>
        </mak_gift>
    </models>
</global>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you correctly declare your models in config.xml ? <global><models><gift><class>Mak_Gift_Model</class></gift></models></global> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your backend model like this:

```
<backend_model>mak_gift/system_config_backend_date</backend_model>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or else you change

```
 <global>
    <models>
        <mak_gift>
            <class>Mak_Gift_Model</class>
        </mak_gift>
    </models>
</global>
```

To

```
    <global>
    <models>
        <gift>
            <class>Mak_Gift_Model</class>
        </gift>
    </models>
</global>
```